Manhwa where mc got chased by some group who wants to kill him when he was a baby
So the story start with mc as baby was taken by his servant to escape from being chased by people, then he hung the baby MC to a tree and used himself as a diversion so that people would chase him. And later some old man founds him and bring to his place that mc got raised with 5 legends if I am not mistaken, one of them got a title as a phantom thieves
